# How to implement TextInput without state [React-native]

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on an app which the users will enter large number of records continously. App functionalities are completed but the performance is bit slow in low end mobiles. As i'm new to react native i've not much idea on this. But when i googled reagrding this issue it has been noticed that when the state changes the whole app get rerenders. So for reducing the state changes i want to know how to use TextInput without using state . Because in my TextInput by using `onChangeText` the state is updating in every keypress.

This is a demo snack of the project [Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@ssoorajs96/demoprjct)

```
  <View style={styles.fixedform}>
    <View style={styles.textinputViewleft}>
        <TextInput 
        style={styles.textinput} 
        ref={firstref}
        label="Digit"
        returnKeyType="next"
        value={digit.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => { setDigit({ value: text, error: '' }); if (text.length === 3) { ref.current.focus(); } }}
        error={!!digit.error}
        errorText={digit.error}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        maxLength={3}
        minLength={3}/>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.textinputView}>
        <TextInput 
        style={styles.textinput} 
        ref={ref}
        label="Count"
        value={count.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => setCount({ value: text, error: '' })}
        error={!!count.error}
        errorText={count.error}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        maxLength={3}/>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.textinputView}>
        <Button loading={loading} disabled={disabled} style={styles.buttonView} mode="contained" onPress={onSubmitPress}>Submit</Button>
    </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: What you want is an uncontrolled component. These use refs to directly access the value at any point, rather than tracking it in real time. While that may help with your problem, having a look at your code the issue is you have a big component with a bunch of logic and state that directly renders a lot of child elements. It's very heavy. You need to start splitting it up into easily manageable and memoizable chunks

Answer (score -1):

Try this way, It will not rerender on text change and hold the value on key press like

```
<TextInput 
        ...
        value={digit.value} // remove this 
        onChangeText={(text) => digit.value = text };
        ...
/>
```

To clear value, try one of this

```
1- firstref.current.clear();
2- firstref.current.setNativeProps({ text: '' });
3- firstref.current.value = '';
```

Comment: So how to reset the value of this TextInput if we do like this